# iPhone screen not responding to touch and can't swipe to unlock

Tags: iphone, ios

I can't figure out why my iPhone 4s isn't working. The screen isn't picking up on my touch, I can't swipe to unlock. I can't turn the phone off as I have to unlock it first which obviously I can't. My guess is to leave it wait for the battery to drain out to force shutdown.

My alarm is going off and will continue to snooze every 10 minutes until I swipe the phone to turn the alarm off, which as stated I *can't*. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can force the phone to restart by holding the lock and home buttons simultaneously for several seconds.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1430

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a damaged digitiser which is embedded above the lcd. 
You can manually disconnect the battery (by opening the back cover) by first removing the two bottom screws. You could also reconnect when ready to see if that solves the issue.